# How do I fetch user information on a webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a webform and I want to pull the logged-in user information using LDAP.

When a user opens the current form, I want to display something like *Hello, USER_NAME, your current status is STATUS*. *USER_NAME*, *STATUS*, and many other fields are stored on another form.

How can I get their values using LDAP?

I already installed LDAP on my website.

I googled, but I didn't find a working example.

Answer (score 1):

1. Figure out the raw ldap queries you need. Outside of php or drupal.
2. Write them down.
3. Use `ldap views` module to make reusable drupal ldap queries. `ldap views` can use tokens and I think parameters in queries ... parameterize as needed.

Then wherever you want your custom message embed the view results onto the page using Context, Panels, hook_page_build .... whatever.